# PHP: Call parent magic method from function of same name

Tags: php

I am using an ORM class - each table in the DB is represented using a subclass of the ORM class.

I am using PHP interfaces, and I wish to specify which methods (db fields) are required in some of my ORM subclasses. Adding a function to an interface requires the method to be explicitly declared in the class. However, these methods rely on magic methods for the actual functionality as the DB structure is unknown to the ORM before run time.

What I imagined doing was creating functions for each, which would return a result from the parent class.

Consider:

```
class ORM
{
    // Library code here. Can't change this.

    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $arguments);
    }
}

interface MyTableInterface
{
    public function myDbField();
}

class MyTable extends ORM implements MyTableInterface
{
    public function myDbField()
    {
        return parent::myDbField();
    }
}
```

With this code, when I call `parent::myDbField()` from the `MyTable` class, it correctly moves to the ORM class and uses the `__call` magic method. Once here, `$this` equals `MyTable` and it calls the original function from the `MyTable` class instead of initiating it's own logic to pull info from the DB.

How can I avoid this recursion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[call](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods) method is only invoked when there is no method found, in your example it is not possible because the method is found in the subclass

Comment: That's what I suspected:( I'll mark your answer correct in a few days if no-one supplies me with a solution. In the meantime, I will change my plans.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it could be passing $orm instance as a dep (constructor, setter or whatever logic). Ex:

```
class MyTable {
    protected $orm;
    public function __construct(Orm $orm)
    {
        $this->orm = $orm;
    }
    public function myDbField()
    {
        return $this->orm->myDbField();
    }
}
```

This way, $this inside Orm __call refers to Orm instance. Perhaps, this could be a scenario to use adapter pattern?

Comment: I'll investigate your suggestion. Thanks.